# Offline Server Still has Quorum Vote

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups

I have an Availability Group with 2 replicas.  One replica is completely powered off. When I look at the cluster quorum info, the server that is powered off still has a quorum vote.  How can that be? I was assuming that with one node offline, that the cluster would not be ble to achieve quorum and the cluster would stop (thus taking the AG offline).

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the "Cluster Quorum Information" screen, the "Vote Count" column indicates if this server is *eligible* to vote, not that it is currently casting it's vote.

Depending on your OS version, configuration, and a few other factors, you are either seeing 50% of voters offline, and thus do not have quorum (in which case the Windows cluster & AG would both be offline & not transacting business), or you are seeing [dynamic quorum](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4434/dynamic-quorum-for-windows-server-2012-r2-cluster-to-support-sql-server-alwayson/) kicking in, which allows you to go down to "last man standing" on the cluster with only a single node online.